# How to add extra field value to the full calendar JS plugin in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, laravel-8

Controller Function to get values from DB

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $getEvents2 = DB::table("appointments_tbl")
        ->join("patients_tbl", function($join){
            $join->on("appointments_tbl.patient_id", "=", "patients_tbl.id");
            })
        ->select("appointments_tbl.start_time","appointments_tbl.end_time", "patients_tbl.status", "patients_tbl.first_name")
        ->get();
        
    $events = [];

    foreach ($getEvents2 as $values) {
        $event = [];
        $event['title'] = $values->first_name;
        $event['status'] = $values->status;
        $event['start'] = $values->start_time;
        $event['end'] = $values->end_time;
        $events[] = $event;
    }

    return $events;
}
```

In the FullCalendar Initialization function, added the function to append the status field value.

```
events: 'getEvents',
            eventDidMount: function(event) {
                $('.fc-event-time').append("<br/>" + event.status);
            },
```

Output is undefined
[image]

Comment: `added the function to append the status field value`...did you? Because that code you showed seems to append the title only (which is already there by default anyway).

Comment: If you want to get the status value, read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing and pay particular attention to the section called "any other property" and what it says about where those properties will be placed in the parsed event object.

Comment: Also your use of `$('.fc-event-time')` means the data is being appended to _every_ event, not just the one the eventDidMount is currently being executed for. Handly, the element you need, containing the current event, is [available in the callback arguments](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) so you can target it directly.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, Your comments helped me alot.

Now the value of status is getting correctly. But I do not know how to show only its respective data, CUrrently all events data are showing in all all events.

`events: 'getEvents',
                eventDidMount: function(info) {
                   var statusText = info.event.extendedProps.status;
                    $('.fc-event-time').append("<br/>" + statusText);
               },`


mycode.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
            events: 'getEvents',
            eventDidMount: function(info) {
                var statusText = info.event.extendedProps.status;
                $(info.el).find('.fc-event-time').append("<br/>" + statusText);
            },
```

Thank you so much for the help!